# How to set chapter layout to default?

Tags: titlesec

I changed my chapter layout using the package "titlesec". Logically, the new layout impacts the heading of the table of contents and the bibliography as both are classified as "chapters".
Is there a way I could set up the layout of these two to default book class layout?
Thanks,
Jiri

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out how to best attack the problem when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\newcommand{\fncchap}{%
\titleformat{\chapter}...}

\newcommand{\oldchap}{%
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter} {0pt}{50pt}{40pt}}

\begin{document}

\oldchap
\tableofcontents

\fncchap
\chapter{Test}


\oldchap
....

\end{document}
```